# Themeforest theme with Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, themes

Can anyone recommend a way to implement a theme from Themeforest with a rails app? I haven't purchased any themes from this site before but I notice that many are provided with php files. As I'm not writing an app in this language I don't want anything that will conflict with the back-end.

Has anyone used such a set up before? Is it possible to just make do with the Html/css files from a theme purchased there?

Any other recommendations for front-end mobile themes suitable for a rails back-end would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out this SO thread - [Ruby on Rails - using a Themeforest Admin Theme with my project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11423762/ruby-on-rails-using-a-themeforest-admin-theme-with-my-project)

Also [Railsthemes](https://railsthemes.com/) sells themes specifically for rails.

Answer (score 0):

These themes are created without the knowledge of the asset pipeline. So for speed and ease I've found it best to skip the asset pipeline all together.

1) Put the theme's javascript and css files into your rails `public` folder.

2) Take the theme's `index.html` file and copy that into `application.html.erb`


These next two steps make sure rails will still work properly.
3) Add these lines within the `<head></head>` section of your newly updated `application.html.erb` file

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
```

4) Add this `<%= yield %>` to the body of your newly updated  `application.html.erb` file

Start the rails server and refresh.